# Right implementation for seq2seq in tensorflow 1.0

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to run a tensorflow code written for tensorflow0.11 and its giving me error

```
tf.nn.seq2seq.model_with_buckets(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'seq2seq'
```

What is the correct implementation in Tensorflow 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the page on [tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.model_with_buckets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/model_with_buckets)

It is legacy code now in Tensorflow r1.0 and above.